# Shadeless node setup still making shades

Tags: materials

I am trying to make a shadeless material in cycles... I tried this setup which i read its supposed to make it shadeless, but still it is has some shades in it, do i need to do something else in order to make it shadeless?

I tried already this setup but it doesnt work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option *Use Nodes* has to be enabled. This can be done in the *Shader Editor* or in the *Material Properties*.

[image: Shader Editor]

[image: Material Properties]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest copying the node group from the Import Images as Planes addon that ships with Blender - import your image and choose the option for Shadeless, and you will see a node group that when expanded looks like this.
[image]